# Renaming files on Ubuntu-GNOME appears weird instead of blue

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, rename

When I try to rename a folder, the selected content looks weird. The selected text should have become white with blue background. Instead it becomes like this :

[image]

I just installed Ubuntu-GNOME and I am getting this. I am using all default themes .

Comment: Bug fixed in GNOME 3.20 ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug and a bug report for this has been filed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1581570. If you have a Launchpad account, you can also let the devs know the bug affects you.